# Como reanudar automaticamente un servidor nodeJs en produccion despues de reiniciar el cloud server

Tags: ubuntu, servidor

he estado buscando la mejor manera de hacer que un cloud server con Ubuntu al reiniciarse, o si tiene una caida por cualquier causa y despues se vuelva a levantarse, se reanude automaticamente el servidor nodeJs que tengo corriendo en El.

Para mantener a node corriendo lo hago con Forever, y para hacer lo que estoy consultando, he encontrado dos maneras:

1. Crontab:

Usando Crontab de la siguiente manera:

```
$ crontab -u myuser -e
```

y en el editor que se abre agregando la siguiente linea

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /your/path/to/your/app.js
```

2. Agregando archivo a $ cd /etc/init.d

Agregar archivo y cambiar permisos de la siguiente manera:

```
$ cd /etc/init.d
$ sudo nano nodeapps
```

en el editor donde se crea nodeapp ponemos la siguiente linea:

```
sudo forever start /ruta/al/script/principal/de/la/app.js
```

Damos permisos de ejecucion:

```
$ sudo chmod +x nodeapps
```

y se agrega el script al arranque:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d nodeapps defaults
```

Bien, mi consulta es cual de estas maneras seria mas estable, o si tienen alguna otra manera mejor de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se hace con PM2 que el gestor de procesos para Nodejs. Primero lo instalas:

```
$ npm install pm2 -g
```

Una vez instalado puedes arrancar tu app.js con PM2 (desde la carpeta en donde se encuentra app.js )

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

Con tus procesos en marcha, arrancados mediante PM2, ahora puedes generar de manera automatizada el correspondiente script, sin tener que preocuparte por la programación, ya que PM2 lo generará para ti. Para ello tenemos el comando siguiente:

```
$ pm2 startup
```

Finalmente guardas este proceso para que cada vez que tu máquina se reinicie app.js también lo haga:

```
$ pm2 save
```

Y listo. Ya puede reiniciar tu máquina y todo funcionará

Algunos comandos de PM2 que te serán útiles:

```
pm2 show 0 [o el número de procesos PM2,  Para ver "gráficamente" tu proceso]
pm2 stop app.js [Para detener el servicio]
pm2 restart app.js [Para reiniciar el servicio]
pm2 reload app.js [Para recargar el servicio]
pm2 delete app.js [Para eliminar el servicio]
pm2 logs [Para ver el log de todos los servicios]
pm2 monit [Para monitorear tus servicios]
```

El sistema se ve mas o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]: